Dracaena reflexa lower leaf loss
My Dracaena reflexa is about 4.5 feet tall now and has lost all but the very top 10 or so leaves. Is this normal? Is there some way to stop this or regrow the bottom leaves? And if not, can I cut off the top healthy part and propagate it?

Please post a photo.

A definite diagnosis is not possible without a picture but in general not enough light or too much water will cause leaf drop on established stems.
These plants react well to being cut back if they are a sunny spot and you have patience.  Check that the stems near the base are firm and not soft or hollow which would happen with root rot.  If they are firm then cut the stems back to six to twelve inches high and put in high light.  Reduce water and wait for new buds to appear.  This could take a month.
